# Getting a "Method Definition not found error" and don't know why

Tags: objective-c

I am going through Apple's Programming with Objective-C and doing the very simple exercises along the way. For some reason I am getting an error saying that a `Method Definition cannot be found`. I've checked for spelling and caps and the method is both in the **.h** and **.m** files. Can't figure out why it's doing it.

Specifically it is saying that the method definition for '*Say Something*' cannot be found. Here is the code:

**.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XYZPerson : NSObject

@property NSString *firstName;
@property NSString *lastName;
@property NSDate *dateOfBirth;

- (void)saySomething;
- (void)sayHello;
- (void)sayShutUp;
- (void)sayHola;
+ (id)person;


@end
```

and the **.m**

```
#import "XYZPerson.h"

@implementation XYZPerson


- (void)saySomething:(NSString *)greeting {
    NSLog(@"%@", greeting);
}

- (void)sayHello {
[self saySomething:@"Hello, World!"];
}

- (void)sayHola {
[self saySomething:@"Hola, Amigos!"];
}
- (void)sayShutUp {
[self saySomething:@"Shut up!"];
}
+ (id)person {
return [[self alloc]init];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A method named `saySomething:` is different than a method named `saySomething`. The former takes an argument, and the latter does not. You'll have to change the declaration in your header file to include an argument. i.e. change:

```
- (void)saySomething;
```

to:

```
- (void)saySomething:(NSString *)greeting;
```

So that it matches your implementation.

Comment: Hi. I am also new to Objective C. Is there any way to automatically create method definition from header to implementation file?